# Limitar o número na caixa de input

Tags: javascript

Queria saber como eu limito o máximo de número antes e depois do ponto.

Tipo, que sejam 3 números antes do ponto e 2 depois. Como faço isso?

Código:

```
<script> 
function soma() 
{
form.campo4.value = parseInt(form.campo1.value*1) * parseInt(form.campo2.value*1) 
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
 $("#demo4").maskMoney({symbol:'R$ ', 
showSymbol:true, thousands:'', decimal:'.', symbolStay: false});
 })

 $(function() {
   $(document).on('click', 'input[value][id=demo4]', function() {
     this.select();
   });

 });
 $("#demo4").bind('input propertychange', function(){
    if($(this).val() > 4){
         $(this).val() = 4;
    }else if($(this).val() < 1){
         $(this).val() = 1;
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Veja a resposta. Se vc ativar o "R$", precisará limitar o campo para 9 caracteres.

Comment: Dvdsamm como eu faço pra por assim no input que vou por o valor eu quero que quando digitar o valor de 1 a 99 ele multiplicar por [ 20 ] e quando for maior de 100 ele multiplicar por [ 23 ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bota `maxlength="9"` no input que você quer fazer isso.

Com isso, o campo não receberá mais do que 5 caracteres digitados (já com o ponto das casas decimais e o símbolo "R$ ").

**Exemplo:** R$ 200.00

Comment: Dvdsamm como eu faço pra por assim no input que vou por o valor eu quero que quando digitar o valor de 1 a 99 ele multiplicar por [ 20 ] e quando for maior de 100 ele multiplicar por [ 23 ]

Comment: @AndréJunior Quando é que vc quer que isso ocorra? Quando sair do foco do campo (blur)?